# Print book vs. printed book

Tags: word-choice

When talking about a physical book, as opposed to an e-book, which is correct: print book or printed book?

Comment: Isn't "book" sufficiently specific?  To my mind the word book refers to a physical object, whereas an e-book refers to a particular type of electronic document.

Comment: If forced to qualify the word, I would choose ["printed book" over "print book,"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=print+book%2C+printed+book&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprint%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprinted%20book%3B%2Cc0) but neither would be my first choice.  I would probably say "real book" or "actual book."

Comment: In "slang"  it's called [dead tree](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116535/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-dead-tree) and here is another related question  [The opposite of paper being a dead-tree](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174395/the-opposite-of-paper-being-a-dead-tree)

Answer (score 4):

As lumberjack pointed out, `book` should suffice here, but I answer to talk about the alternatives.

When talking about one individual book, and to set it apart from an eBook, using `printed book` is more common than using `print book`. As in,

> "I bought a printed book"

Although in my opinion, in this situation, you're better off using the classic terms of [paperback](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/paperback) or [hardback](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/hardback). As in:

> I bought a paperback (or hardback)

---

`Print books` is used rarely, and mostly in formal situations

[Print](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/print?q=printed) isn't really an adjective. But one of its senses is this:

> [uncountable] used to refer to the business of producing newspapers, magazines and books

which is used to form compound nouns like `print media` or `print unions`. `Print books` would be uncommon and sound a bit formal, but it's not unheard-of.

But, since `print` technically refers to the whole business, proper usage would require it to be used in that context. As in:

> Our survey shows that readers prefer buying eBooks over print books.

(Printed books is equally applicable here.)

[Source - Oxford]

Comment: I have recently produced a book and during the promotional stages am being asked whether it is an ebook, soft cover (paperback) or hard cover (hardback).  A book today can exist in digital or paper versions.  I agree that *print*, as an adjective is rather arcane, but it is a useful collective adjective embracing hard and soft cover paper books, as opposed to digital books, and I prefer it to *printed*.